# How to insert an object into a json object/array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a json object that contains multiple parent items (denoted by the parent property being null) which has nested child objects.

```
{
  "aggregateId": null,
  "aggregateList": {
    "name": "My Grocery Store",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Vegetables",
        "documentType": "Produce",
        "parent": null,
        "count": 2,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Carrots",
            "documentType": "Produce",
            "parent": null,
            "count": 1447,
            "children": null
            },
            {
            "name": "Lettuce",
            "documentType": "Produce",
            "parent": null,
            "count": 311,
            "children": null
            }]
      },
      {
        "name": "Canned Goods",
        "documentType": "Cans",
        "parent": null,
        "count": 583,
        "children": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is when a new object which is a child is returned insert it into the existing array. So for example the object Celery is returned

```
{
    "name": "Celery",
    "documentType": "Produce",
    "parent": null,
    "count": 100,
    "children": null
}
```

Iterate through the tree, locate its parent (produce) and insert it into that array.

```
{
      "aggregateId": null,
      "aggregateList": {
        "name": "My Grocery Store",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Vegetables",
            "documentType": "Produce",
            "parent": null,
            "count": 2,
            "children": [{
                "name": "Carrots",
                "documentType": "Produce",
                "parent": null,
                "count": 1447,
                "children": null
                },
                {
                "name": "Lettuce",
                "documentType": "Produce",
                "parent": null,
                "count": 311,
                "children": null
                },
                {
                 "name": "Celery",
                 "documentType": "Produce",
                 "parent": null,
                 "count": 100,
                 "children": null
                 }]
          },
          {
            "name": "Canned Goods",
            "documentType": "Cans",
            "parent": null,
            "count": 583,
            "children": null
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

So far I've tried to iterate through the collection using a for statement but this doesn't seem right and I am not getting results returned. The part that doesn't seem fight is in specifying the location in the tree.

Is there a way via javascript to take the object/array and look at each property to locate the matching value and then insert the new object into that array?

**Update:**

Sorry I didn't include enough code. 
The for loop is wrapped in a function

```
    function nestAssociation(node, oldCollection, newAggregates)
       {
           var parent = node.documentType; //the parent value of the collection to be inserted
           var currentCollection = oldCollection; //previous collection
           var newCollection = newAggregates; //the object to be inserted (Celery)

for (var i = 0, iLen = arrayCount; i < iLen; i++) {
               if ($scope.myList.children[0].children[i].documentType == node.documentType) {
                   console.log('true');
                  var myNewList = $scope.myList.children.concat(newCollection.children)
                  $scope.myList = myNewList;
                   console.log(myNewList)
            }
}
```

Comment: should it be `node.parent` (small "P")?

Comment: i'm also a bit confused...why do you compare to `node` but then `concat(newCollection.children)` instead of `concat(node.children)`?

Comment: @adilapapaya Thanks that was a typo. That was not the issue with the code though

Comment: And one more question: `parent` is always null...it seems like the field that contains the parent info is `documentType` so why do you compare to `node.parent` instead of `node.documentType`?

Comment: thanks another typo I have updated the post

Comment: You should use JSON only as a transport protocol and implement/use a data structure which supports your needs.